# WCAG 2.0 Using tables for layout

Tags: html-table, accessibility, wcag

Does WCAG 2.0 allow tables for layout, I can't see anything in the guidelines saying you can't but this suprises me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H73.html

> Although WCAG 2 does not prohibit the
>   use of layout tables, CSS-based
>   layouts are recommended in order to
>   retain the defined semantic meaning of
>   the HTML table elements and to conform
>   to the coding practice of separating
>   presentation from content

Answer (score 4):

I'd add to @jordan answer that imbricated tables are inaccessible.
A layout table must avoid using any element used in data tables, that is:

- no `caption`, `thead`, `tfoot` and `th` elements (only `table`, `tr`, `td` and optionally `tbody`)
- `summary` attribute (it can be empty), `headers`, `scope` (only `rowspan` and `colspan`. And `id` obviously)
- strange things like `axis` or `col` element

It must also be linearizable, that is, must make sense when cells are read from top to bottom and left to right.

Relevant **WCAG 2.0** Failure Techniques are:

- [F46: Failure (...) due to using th elements, caption elements, or non-empty summary attributes in layout tables](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/F46.html)
- [F49: Failure (...) due to using an HTML layout table that does not make sense when linearized](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/F49.html)

*Note:* if you're using tables only for design constraints, then FYI you can use `display: table;` (and `table-row` and `table-cell`) on every browser except IE6 and IE7.